# will apache server configuration work after upgrade(using alternate cd) from ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

will apache server configuration work after upgrade(using alternate cd) from ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, but it's hard to say for certain without know what custom changes you've made.

If you followed general Ubuntu / Debian config guidelines for apache (using the /etc/apache2/conf.d, sites-available, sites-enabled, and other config dirs), then you should be fine.